# Comparing this.props.prop and nextProps.prop with mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Is there any way to do something like this with mobx?

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.prop !== nextProps.prop) {
    /* side effect, ex. router transition */
  }
}
```

From my experience, `this.props.prop` is always equal to `nextProps.prop` even in `componentWill-` hooks...

***UPD*** Here is more specific use case — simple login scenario:

**Store**

```
class AppStore {
  @observable viewer = new ViewerStore();
}

class ViewerStore {
  @observable id;
  @observable name;
  @observable error;

  fromJSON(json = {}) {
    this.id = json.id;
    this.name = json.name;
  }

  clearError() {
    this.error = null;
  }

  login({ email, password }) {
    fetch('/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
      }),
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
    .then(json => {
      this.fromJSON(json);
    })
    .catch(({ error }) => {
      this.error = error;
    })
  }
}
```

**React part**

```
class LogInPage extends Component {
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.viewer.id && !this.props.viewer.id) {
      this.props.viewer.clearError();
      this.props.onSuccess();
    }
  }

  login = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.viewer.login({
      email: e.target.elements['email'].value,
      password: e.target.elements['password'].value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Log In</h1>
        <form onSuccess={this.login}>
          <input type="text" name="email" />
          <input type="password" name="password" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        { this.props.viewer.error && (
          <div>
            <b>Error</b>: {this.props.viewer.error}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const store = new AppStore();
ReactDOM.render(<LogInPage 
  viewer={store.viewer}
  onSuccess={() => alert("Hello!")}  
 />
, container);
```

So basically, I just want to be able to do something when viewer `id` switches from `undefined` to something

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the update, that clarifies the question a lot. It depends a bit on what you want to do, but if you want to change the rendering of your component, it is enough to decorate your component with `@observer` from the `mobx-react` package. It will then automatically re-render when the store changes.

If you want do any additional actions, you can setup an autorun in your `componentWillMount`. Like

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.autorunDisposer = mobx.autorun(() => {
        if (nextProps.viewer.id && !this.props.viewer.id) {
            this.props.viewer.clearError();
            this.props.onSuccess();
        }
    })
}
```

But I don't see this pattern very often, as often it is cleaner to have this kind of logic just in your store. Personally I would expect a login form component to rougly look like this:

```
@observer class RequiresLogin extends Component {
    render() {
        if (this.props.viewerStore.id !== undefined) {
            return this.props.children
        } else {
            return <LoginPage viewer={this.props.viewerStore}/>
        }
    }
}

@observer class MyTestPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return <RequiresLogin viewer={this.props.viewerStore}>
            Secret Area!
        </RequiresLogin>
    }
}

@observer class LogInPage extends Component {
  login = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.viewer.login({
      // tip: use React refs or the onChange handler to update local state:
      email: e.target.elements['email'].value,
      password: e.target.elements['password'].value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.viewer.id)
        return null; // no need to show login form
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Log In</h1>
        <form onSuccess={this.login}>
          <input type="text" name="email" />
          <input type="password" name="password" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        { this.props.viewer.error && (
          <div>
            <b>Error</b>: {this.props.viewer.error}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But how do I access `nextProps` in `componentWillMount()` ?

Comment: @mweststrate Is this answer still up to date? It seems like an exceptionally common use case. I'm rendering a flatlist in RN and want to scroll to bottom when the length increases. MobX is forcing me to jump through crazy hoops to simply compare prevProps to this.props. What's the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In 99,9% of cases, this happens because somewhere else in your code props are mutated directly.  And this is not allowed in react.

Typical scenario's include:

```
var myObject = this.props.someObject;  // myObject is a POINTER to props, not copy
myObject.attribute = newAttribute;     // Now props are directly mutated

var myArray = this.props.someArray;
myArray.splice(a,b);                   // splice directly mutates array
```

To solve, make a proper copy of the props object before you update the prop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually the problem happened because I passed a `mobx` store as the single prop (in order to call it's methods like `this.props.store.update()`), so even though when something changes in store, component is updated by `mobx`, `nextProps` still holds the same reference to that store.

I finally ended up with destructuring store into component's props, when I need this kind of check.

Comment: Can you describe why the route has to be changed, and why that has to be the responsibility by the component that receives the whole store? I would expect that to happen in a store that receives a specific item for example. Maybe share some code?